# Current item in Viewpager changes with different orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I have a fragment, which consists of a viewPager in the top of the screen and two buttons at the bottom.
The buttons are for an additional navigation besides the swiping through the pages.
The viewPager consists of about 10 pages with some input fields.

However, when I swipe through the pages and rotate my phone to landscape, the viewPager automatically changes the current item and selects the first page again. Another effect is, that all input data to this point are cleared.
This is really annoying because you have to start all over again.
Is it possible to switch between landscape and portrait mode without this issues?

Some background information:

- the app consists of one activity, which is filled with different fragments
- a navigation drawer is implemented to choose which fragment will be shown

Comment: You should include some codes in your background information section

Comment: Add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your mainifest. It will stop calling oncreate() of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

When you change orientation you are essentially refreshing your activity losing your data such as current page, fragment etc, you need to save your data across the states, i would suggest looking into savedInstanceState.